# How to crop empty white space in PDF file using Preview on Mac?

Tags: macos, pdf, imagemagick, crop

There is a comic book PDF file which has a lot of white space at the bottom.

The content is almost half the length of the page size.

How to crop all pages in the PDF file?

I have tried `imagemagick` but the quality is poor.

`convert  -verbose -density 300 -interlace none -quality 100 output.pdf`

Comment: Your questions is a bit ambiguous. You used ImageMagick, but asked about Mac Preview. Please be more clear. Also, please always provide your commands or code when asking questions on this forum and your input file. Please refer to this forum's help section for information on how to ask good questions and what are appropriate questions. I have made a suggestion below in an answer.

Comment: added the code snippet @fmw42

Comment: Your code has no input image! -quality likely has no effect. I do not think ImageMagick can change the interlace or the quality of the result. Can you post a link to your PDF?

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick, try using a larger density and then resize by the inverse amount in percent. Here, I use density = 4*72 = 288 and then resize by 25% (1/4).

```
convert -density 288 image.pdf -resize 25% -fuzz 15% -trim +repage result.pdf
```